# Remove DotNET menu dropdown grey area for icons

Tags: vb.net, menu, drop-down-menu

How do I remove the area in a dropdown menu where the menu item icons are typically displayed?

[DropDownMenuGreyAreaHeadAche http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/MenuImageBar.png](http://en.wiki.mcneel.com/content/upload/images/MenuImageBar.png)

I just need to remove the grey area in this particular dropdown, other dropdowns of menu items in the same menu bar need to retain this area because they do have icons.

Edit: This is WinForms.

Comment: Usual first question: WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Edited, this is for WinForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the `ShowImageMargin` property of the menu to `false`

Comment: Thanks! I had to cast the dropdown to ToolStripDropDownMenu first (it's only exposed as ToolStripDropDown which doesn't have the ShowImageMargin property).